# How to use the RTC-Client 2.0.0 to create a J2EE project to do the jsp?

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I want to ask a question about the RTC-Client 2.0.0. I want to use the RTC-Client-2.0.0 to create a project (I guess the type of the project is J2EE) to create the .jsp. However, I cannot find any J2EE project type when I click the 'New > Project'.

Do I need to install something or do other things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would probably be to get [Eclipse Galileo (3.5.x) IDE **for Java EE** developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/galileo/sr2) (which provide the everything required for Java EE development) and to install Rational Team Concert on top of it. The Jazz team provides official instruction on their website, check out [Tech Tip: Installing the Rational Team Concert client into Eclipse 3.5.x](http://jazz.net/library/techtip/384).